# Custom Alexa Skill not working on echo dot but works on simulator

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I've written my first Alexa Skill and it appears to work fine on the simulator as provided in the developer console however when I try to launch it on my echo dot. It doesn't appear to work. I am from Canada and thus have added English (CA) version as well to the interaction model. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to recognize it. It just had a short two tone(?) beep sound.

Comment: I had trouble with the different en- types as well. It was easiest to simply delete all except US (even if you're targeting Canada, the UK etc.) and then build out from there once it works. Also the documentation didn't make it clear but you are far better off only ever modifying the json directly and not touching the UI in the dashboard, because whenever you repush an update it will overwrite any dashboard changes. That way if you remove a language it's easy for the model to quietly get readded or out of sync for a particular locale.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I originally had the en-US and it didn't work either. After searching online on the Amazon forums and Stackoverflow, they mentioned to target the particular region that you are in and that is why I added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I forgot to setup my echo dot again with my developer account (I previously was using a regular account).